# jDBI createStatement from a file

Tags: java, jdbi

I want to put my query commands in a sql file, and then using `createStatement` read the query from the file and do the binding.

Doing `h.createStatement("SOME LONG QUERY WITH BUNCH OF JOINS AND WHERES IS HARD TO READ IN JAVA")` is not very legible.

What's the best way, other than using `File` to open and read the file?

Answer (score 1):

Jdbi provides the [`ClasspathSqlLocator`](http://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/jdbi/v3/core/locator/ClasspathSqlLocator.html) class to read files on the classpath.

For example, this returns the content of the file `query.sql` which is inside the folder `jdbiTest` on the classpath:

```
String query = ClasspathSqlLocator.findSqlOnClasspath("jdbiTest.query");
```

Link to the documentation: http://jdbi.org/#_classpathsqllocator

Comment: I'm still on jDBI 2. This doesn't exist for jDBI 2 or something equivalent of it?

Comment: I see there is `UseST4StatementLocator`. I'll take a look at that